# implicit declaration of function ‘strrev’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]

Tags: c

I am trying to reverse a string. But when I compiled my code using `gcc filename` it reports the following error:

> gcc itoa.c itoa.c: In function ‘main’: itoa.c:9:21: warning: implicit
>   declaration of function ‘strrev’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration] 
>   printf("S=%s \t \n",strrev(s));
>                        ^
>
> itoa.c:9:8: warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’,
>   but argument 2 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat=]  printf("S=%s \t
>   \n",strrev(s));
>           ^
>
> /tmp/ccK1YuDL.o: In function `main': itoa.c:(.text+0x38): undefined
>   reference to`strrev' collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

My src code is :

```
#include<stdio.h>  
#include <string.h>   
int main() {
    char s[10]="ZAkir";  
    printf("S=%s \t \n",strrev(s));  
    return 0;  
}
```

Comment: `strrev` is not part of the standard c library.